# File Trigger not working in Automation Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, import, automationstudio

We had a successfully running file import running in Automation Studio that was working each time a file was placed onto the FTP.  Our internal system failed to drop a new file, causing the import to fail.

We put a new file onto the FTP and the listener isn't triggering the import now.  Is there a step that we're missing to get the imports to automatically restart?

Comment: Make sure you are listening to the right folder. Would help if you can take a screen shot.

Comment: nothing changed in the folder, but I will check

Comment: Also try stopping and starting the automation again.

Comment: If it fails it doesn't automatically restart

Comment: so, the question is - how do we restart it?

Comment: will answer now

Comment: Hi George..how are you getting along? Did my answer work for you?

Comment: It didn't solve the issue.  SFMC support has escalated to level 2

Comment: yikes! Hope they resolve it soon!

Comment: Update:  There was an issue with the FTP and the Parent/Child relationship.

_The automation was created prior to creating the ftp for the child BU, so it was looking at the parent level ftp. 

Since the automation had already been created it was still looking at the parent level folder for the trigger. 

When the automation was paused and reactivated, it looked at the newly created ftp._

Answer (score 1):

If an automation fails, it will not be restarted automatically. To restart the automation, you would have to diagnose it and correct what made it fail (in your case you have done this). You will then have to restart the automation.

Go to your automation and select the file location for the trigger in the workflow tab and save it. This should work now.